# Forcing TLS 1.1 or higher on node.js

Tags: node.js, ssl

I'm trying to create a server that would use TLS 1.1 or higher.

This is my current TLS configuration:

```
var options = {};
options.key  = fs.readFileSync('privatekey.pem');
options.cert = fs.readFileSync('certificate.pem');
options.secureProtocol = 'TLSv1_server_method';
options.ciphers = "AES128-GCM-SHA256:RC4:HIGH:!MD5:!aNULL:!EDH";
options.honorCipherOrder = true;
httpServer = https.createServer(options, app);
```

Just as was suggested [here](http://nodejs.org/dist/v0.10.17/docs/api/tls.html#tls_tls_createserver_options_secureconnectionlistener)

From reading Openssl's guide [here](http://www.openssl.org/docs/ssl/ssl.html#DEALING_WITH_PROTOCOL_METHODS) I didn't find anything about TLS 1.1

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TLS 1.0 should no longer be used.
This works to disable TLS 1.0 in node.js:

```
https.createServer({
        secureOptions: require('constants').SSL_OP_NO_TLSv1,
        pfx: fs.readFileSync(path.resolve(pathToCert))
    }, app).listen(443);
```

You can verify this using this tool:
[ssllabs](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/)

Answer (score 1):

This did the trick:

```
options.secureProtocol = 'SSLv23_server_method';
options.ciphers = "AES128-GCM-SHA256:HIGH:!MD5:!aNULL:!EDH";
```

The right place to look for it was [here](https://www.openssl.org/docs/ssl/SSL_CTX_new.html)

Comment: Are you certain this prevented TLS 1? Using these ciphers I'm still able to get TLS 1.0 to work.

Comment: try options.secureProtocol = 'TLSv1_2_server_method';

Comment: Yes. That too proved to be unsuccessful. What version of Node were you running?

Comment: As a follow up, it was an OpenSSL / Node.js version thing. Updating Node.js (which in turn updated OpenSSL) solved the issue.