# How to disable tls 1.0 and use only tls 1.1 using nodejs

Tags: node.js, ssl

I want to disable the TLS v1.0 and use TLS 1.1 and above only.

By nodejs, I use the `https` module, how to set the https options?

I have read the api doc [node api tls](https://nodejs.org/api/tls.html), but I still don't know how to set this.

I think it depends on the `secureProtocol` and `cipher`, but I just don't know how to set the value.

My node version is 0.10.36, and openssl version is 0.9.8j.

Comment: I think the answer is already here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22805730/forcing-tls-1-1-or-higher-on-node-js

Comment: @B3rn475 I see, but it seems doesn't work...

Answer (score 9):

Marco's solution worked for me, but as TLS 1.1 is also considered a vulnerability, it is better to disable both and go with TLS 1.2

```
const { constants } = require('crypto')
https.createServer({
    secureOptions: constants.SSL_OP_NO_TLSv1 | constants.SSL_OP_NO_TLSv1_1
    pfx: fs.readFileSync(path.resolve(pathToCert))
}, app).listen(443)
```

Answer (score 7):

TLS 1.0 should no longer be used. This works to disable TLS 1.0 in node.js:

```
https.createServer({
    secureOptions: require('constants').SSL_OP_NO_TLSv1,
    pfx: fs.readFileSync(path.resolve(pathToCert))
}, app).listen(443);
```

You can verify this using this tool: [ssllabs](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/)

Comment: Hum, I have tried this, including disabled 1.1 with strange results. Firefox and whynopadlock are both still complaining about TLS, but Chrome is okay with it.

Answer (score 4):

The use of the constants module is undocumented. A better way to disable TLS v1.0 would be to use constants from the crypto module instead. See the [documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html#crypto_crypto_constants_1) on the Node.js website for reference.

The solution then becomes the following:

```
const { constants } = require('crypto')
https.createServer({
    secureOptions: constants.SSL_OP_NO_TLSv1,
    pfx: fs.readFileSync(path.resolve(pathToCert))
}, app).listen(443)
```

Answer (score 4):

This will be helpful if any one is using MEANjs

use

```
secureProtocol: 'TLSv1_2_server_method',
```

instead of

```
secureProtocol: 'TLSv1_method',
```

file location config/lib/socket.io.js

Works without issue.[image]