# How to disallow TLS 1.0 on spdy?

Tags: node.js, ssl, spdy

I need to disallow users connecting over TLS 1.0 for security reasons.

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31201029/how-to-disable-tls-1-0-and-use-only-tls-1-1-using-nodejs) suggests if using HTTPS module for node I can do the following:

```
    const { constants } = require('crypto');
    const options = {
      key: key,
      cert: cert,
      ca: ca,
      secureOptions: constants.SSL_OP_NO_TLSv1
    };
https.createServer(options);
```

However, I am using [spdy](https://www.npmjs.com/package/spdy). I hoped I could pass HTTPS options through and it would utilise them but doesn't seem to be the case. Does anyone know how I can achieve this using this package?